# JQuery - Random "XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, parsing

I have the following (jquery) javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "%URL HERE%",
  dataType: "xml",
  async: false,
  success: function(xml) {
    console.log(xml);
    var root = $(xml).find("root");
    var child = root.find("child");
    console.log(child);
  },
  error: function(){
    console.log("error encountered while fetching xml");
  } 
});
```

Which fetches the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child id="test1">Content</child>
</root>
```

Which does do what it should do, except a little bit after successfully executing the code and logging the correct data, the following error pops up in the console:

> XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: `</input>`.
>   Location: 
>   Line Number 1, Column 15:

I am utterly confused as to what causes this error. The actual script runs successfully and nowhere in my files there's an `<input>` (or `<input />`).

After isolating, this is the only javascript left in the file (together with the link to a jquery cdn) so it's also not the case of another piece of code throwing this instead.

It doesn't seem to interrupt code at all either, it's just this random error popping up each time a bit after having done the ajax call - in particular after having done the `$(xml).find("root")`. If I comment this out, the ajax request happens but the error doesn't pop up - but well my code obviously doesn't work either then!

I hope anyone can give me some insight as to why this error pops up as I've been staring at this for many hours now and I only seem to understand it less and less...

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log()` the response when the error happens to ensure the XML returned is *exactly* as you're expecting it to be?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the sample code, I log the XML and it seems to return the XML as it should be. The error happens after all finished successfully after all.

Comment: Does the error show up EVERY time this code is executed?  I.e., could it be an issue with your HTML, or with a browser plugin that's dumping messages to the console? If it shows every time you run and rerun this snippet of code (not a page reload, just execution of this snippet of code), then presumably it's caused by this code.

Comment: Yes, it happens every single time I execute this code. If I run it 4 times after eachother, the error pops up 4 times too. I put this code in a fully basic HTML file (empty body and stuff) to exclude any HTML related issues as well and it still happens.
Also, I don't use browser plugins but even then, it happens cross-browser for me.

Comment: jQuery version?

Comment: @C1rdec That was the problem! No idea what exactly went wrong still, but it got fixed by using a newer version of jQuery. Somehow I managed to find an import link of jquery 1.10.1. Now I replaced it with a jQuery 3.3.1 and the error no longer shows up. Thanks alot for hinting me towards that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stopped showing up after using a newer version of jQuery. I was somehow using jQuery 1.10.1 before, now 3.3.1 and that got rid of the error.